# ILookup versus IGrouping

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

ILookup and IGrouping are pretty similar Linq interfaces.
Both bound a key to a list of values.

The question is what differs these both interface.

Does anyone have an example what you can do with one type that you are not able to todo with the other one?

When should you use "group by" and when "to lookup"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call `ToLookup` if you need to lookup values by key, but you don't need ordering.

You should call `GroupBy` if you just need to loop through the groups.